# WebRTC on Chrome; how do I know if it's using UDP or TCP

Tags: sockets, google-chrome, tcp, udp, webrtc

I'm currently playing around with WebRTC on Chrome behind a company firewall, using Google's demo app at: https://apprtc.appspot.com. Is there any sure-fire way to determine whether the connection being made to another app user outside my company firewall is via UDP or streaming TCP through Google's STUN/TURN server? chrome://webrtc-internals provides a lot of stats, but nothing obvious to me. Or is there an API call I can make during the session to determine the transport type? Thanks

=========== UPDATE ==============

FYI, [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/zzvlGLkwaGE) provides more information - press 'i' when using the demo app will show if using a TURN server (but not if using tcp/udp).

Comment: What operating system are you working on?

Comment: Actually, that does not appear to matter. Would something like WireShark (https://www.wireshark.org/) work? That allows you to monitor traffic in and outbound on a machine, and it appears to be available on all platforms (Windows, OS X and Linux). If you know the IP of the other end, you can filter the packets, and then from there see what type of packet they are. Typically, all of the media streaming packets involved in WebRTC is UDP, where the signaling bits, I think, are typically TCP.

Comment: it's OSX - I was hoping that the info is buried somewhere in the Chrome WebRTC-internals data. Is wireshark similar to Netstat?

Comment: WireShark is similar to netstat, but in my experience, WireShark has much more detailed information. WireShark includes the entire packet being sent and received. So, you can actually look at the contents of the packets (although the contents of the media packets are encrypted, so have fun reading those). But, you will be able to at least see all of the information for each packet. I would suggest either filtering traffic, or not doing anything else while WireSharking, as there will be tons of packets printing to the program.

Comment: Updated my answer with info on getting it programatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wireshark will work fine for that.  On Firefox, you can go to about:webrtc, click on the peerconnection, and see which candidates from ICE were selected (and if they're TCP or UDP, etc).

[image: about:webrtc on Firefox]

[edit - added] 
Programmatically, you can look at the type of candidates using statistics reports, such as in [this example](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/master/src/content/peerconnection/constraints/js/main.js#L221-241) and [this PR](https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc/pull/99/files) and using the type property.  You may have to parse the SDP to get the priority from the Candidates in Firefox. (thanks to Fippo for pointing this out).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm restricted to using Chrome and not firefox

Comment: The about:webrtc ICE Stats report on Firefox is desperately needed for Chrome!  Chrome's webrtc-internals is definitely harder to read, especially when you're trying to debug a webrtc connection real-time.

Comment: Chrome WebRTC traffic can be viewed via `chrome://webrtc-internals/`